# How to set a state variable in the parent of a React Route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am having fun implementing routing in my app, but find it hard to set a page title in the parent with the name of the screen that Route is rendering, like this:

```
class App...
  setTitle(title) {
      this.state.screentitle = title
      this.setState(this.state)
  }
  ...
  <h1>{this.state.title}</h1}
  ...
  <Route path='/Search' render={props => <ScreenSearch setTitle={this.setTitle} {...props} />} />
```

and each child holds the actual title text, like:

```
class ScreenSearch...
  componentDidMount() {
      this.props.setTitle("Search");
  }
```

While this actually works, I would prefer to keep the title texts for all child screens in the parent, together with all `Route` rules. After all, the child objects should do just their job, like implementing a search page, but have no need to know what it is called at the parent level.

Also, this seems a complex way with too much code to just set a stupid title.

As a beginner with React Route, I would like to ask if there is a better way.

Comment: Personally I try to avoid child components calling up to parent components wherever possible.  Further I agree with your intuition that "After all, the child objects should do just their job, like implementing a search page, but have no need to know what it is called at the parent level".  The route should determine which child components to show and how to set the title IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a `Layout` component that will have shared items on it like page title,navigations etc.
Layout Component

```
class DefaultLayout extends React.Component{  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="header">
          <h1>Company Name</h1>
          <Navigation />
        </dv>
        <div className="content">
          <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
        <div className="footer">
          <p>Copyright (c) 2014 Company Name</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }  
};

module.exports = DefaultLayout;
```

and the child page

```
var React = require('react');
var DefaultLayout = require('./DefaultLayout');

class PageOne extends React.Component{
  this.state={
     title:"Page 1"
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <DefaultLayout title={this.props.title}>
        <p>The page's content...</p>
        <p>goes here.</p>
      </DefaultLayout>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for; react-routing is apparently not that great. But this seems the best work-around.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to implement it, if you have many routes you can create your own Route component where you give the title as a prop

```
<Route path='/Search' render={props => {
  this.state.screentitle!==this.setTitle && this.setTitle(this.setTitle)
  return <ScreenSearch  {...props} />} 
/>
```

After seeing your comment I understand you want to remove the set Title so you will need the location from react-router and an object something like this:

```
let routeTitles = { 
   /'search': 'The search' , 
  '/jobs': 'Look for a job'  
}
<Title>{routeTitles[this.props.location.pathname]}</Title>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have tried this already and needed to add a call to `setState` and got an infinite loop, and a warning that render should be a pure function :-(

Comment: holy shit what have i done hahahahahahahaha i get it now sorry, will try to fix it  by testing it first

Comment: and you may need to write a route component, and give these as a prop

Comment: Looks good but I am still puzzled why this.setTitle() needs to call itself. I'll definitely try all this, probably monday. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Now i understood our question, check the final answer :) I deserve  the reps of that upvote and accepted answer heheheheh gimme

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for. Clever trick with the array of titles, although it needs duplication of the routing paths. I still find this worthwhile to give it a try. Thanks! +1